# Polymer CLI: SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install the polymer CLI from here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli

However, after installing it I get an error when trying to run `polymer help`:

```
[~/Documents/roottest]$ polymer help                                                                                                                                                                                   ruby:2.2.4

/opt/boxen/nodenv/versions/v0.10.26/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/bin/polymer.js:19
  let lib = path ? require(path) : require('..');
  ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
[~/Documents/roottest]$ node --version                                                                                                                                                                                 ruby:2.2.4
v0.10.26
[~/Documents/roottest]$ nodenv --version                                                                                                                                                                               ruby:2.2.4
nodenv 0.3.3
```

My node version is v0.10.26, my nodeenv version is 0.3.3. I'm using Mac.

Does anyone know how I would fix this?

Comment: Do you have 'use strict'; line included in the beginning of the file? The ^^^ are poiting at 'let' which is ES6 syntax, the older versions of Node.js don't support it out of the box as far as I know.

Comment: where? i am just trying ton install polymer cli

Comment: 'let' is another version of creating a variable in Javascript, it requires EcmaScript 6 support. There are some flags you can pass to node when tryiing to execute a file, `harmony` might be the keyword you're looking after.

Answer (score 1):

Polymer CLI is not compatible with Node v0.10.26.

The [setup guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli) indicates that Node 4.x or newer is required. You should actually upgrade to the [latest stable version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) (6.2.0).

[image]